# Issue when trying to use getResourceAsStream in java

Tags: java, file-io

So basically I have two lines in my code that are as follows:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/config");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

and my file structure in eclipse is as follows (image posted):

[image]

When I try to run this code, I get NullPointerExceptions when it reaches the second line (BufferedReader line). I can't for the life of me figure out why InputStream "is" is becoming null. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `getResourceAsStream("qbooksprintfix/resources/config")`. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280628/2581401)

Comment: @c.s. Duh, that worked!

Comment: @AndyThomas: the path is relative to the package of the class whan Class.getResourceAsStream is used, but not when ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() is used. In the latter case, the path is always absolute.

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks for the correction. I saw *getResourceAsStream()* and totally overlooked the preceding *getClassLoader()*.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using a classloader to load a stream, the path you are using is always an absolute path (so you *should not* use a leading `/` in this case) and should start with your root package. In your case this is under `src`.

So since your resource is under package `qbooksprintfix/resources` you should access it like:

`getResourceAsStream("qbooksprintfix/resources/config")`

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceAsStream()` looks in the classpath for the item, so the "base" directory for it in your case is probably `src`:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("qbooksprintfix/resources/config");
```

Comment: When using a classloader's `getResourceAsStream()` all paths are absolute so you should not use a starting `/`

Comment: @c.s. Ah!  I generally do `getResourceAsStream()` from `Class` rather than `ClassLoader` so didn't know there was a difference!

Comment: Yes that's their main difference. Please fix your answer so I remove my downvote

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
getResourceAsStream("qbooksprintfix/resources/config");
```

or preferably

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("qbooksprintfix/resources/config");
```