# NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION when reading config.properties

Tags: java

I am getting File not found when reading `config.properties`. `config.properties` is rightly there under `com/wu/resources`. What could be the issue?

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

InputStream input;
input = Readproperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/wu/resources/config.properties");
if (input != null) {
  prop.load(input); }
else {
  System.out.println("file not found");
}
```

Comment: try input = Readproperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");

Comment: Drop the leading `/` - you're calling `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, not `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: @wero - /com/wu/resources is under src ...is there a way to attach screenshot here?

Comment: @Nick - Read.properties and config.properties are in different packages,so putting direct value of config.properties also doesnt work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException when reading a properties file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139532/nullpointerexception-when-reading-a-properties-file-in-java)

Comment: Okay, then you will have to provide relative path and not absolute path

Comment: @PanayappanSwaminathan did you put it in `src/main/resources` or just in `src` ?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks, after removing / , it worked. How does this / makes difference between Class and Class loader

Comment: In `Class.getResourceAsStream`, "/" is used to "root" the resource name, because otherwise it will be treated as relative to the class. That's not the case for `ClassLoader`, because there's no class for it to be relative to. See the docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) returns null, which then causes Properties.load to throw NullPointerException.

[URL getResource(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29): Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.
    The name of a resource is a **'/'**-separated path name that identifies the resource.

**Returns** : A **URL** object for reading the resource, or **null** if:

- the resource could not be found, or
- the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
input = Readproperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/com/wu/resources/config.properties");
```